# Infinite recursion using micronaut and gorm

Tags: micronaut

I come from Grails background and have recently started a project in Micronaut using GORM.

I have the following code:

```
package micronaut.query.association.domain
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity
@grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
class Author implements GormEntity<Author> {
    String name
    static hasMany = [
        books: Book
    ]
    static mapping = {
        books fetch: 'join'
    }
}

package micronaut.query.association.domain

import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity

@grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
class Book implements GormEntity<Book> {
    String name
    Author author
}

package micronaut.query.association
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import micronaut.query.association.domain.Author
import grails.gorm.transactions.ReadOnly

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
@Controller("/author")
class AuthorController {

    @Get("/")
    @ReadOnly
    List<Author> index() {
        return Author.list()
    }
}
```

The app compiles and starts without problems, but when I try to access  the url http:localhost:8080/author, I receive the following error:

> 10:25:29.431 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR
>   i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Error
>   encoding object [[micronaut.query.association.domain.Author : 1,
>   micronaut.query.association.domain.Author : 2]] to JSON: Infinite
>   recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
>   micronaut.query.association.domain.Book["author"]-

| Micronaut Version: 1.0.1
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_192
OS: Linux 4.19.4-arch1-1-ARCH

Am  I doing something wrong?
Thanks and please forgive me if my message was not posted in the correct way. This is my first try in stack overflow.

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the excellent article suggested, I was able to solve the problem.

The solution was decorate the books declaration in the Author class with the @JsonManagedReference annotation and decorate the author declaration in the Book class withe the @JsonBackReference annotation.

Comment: Note you get a very similar issue if you have an injected field e.g. a Service. In that case use @JsonIgnore